# Changing id of a dataProvider in Flashbuilder

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder, dataprovider

I'm using Flashbuilder for this. I have a button that changes the id of a dataProvider like this:

```
result.datagrid.dataProvider="lineup_1";
```

However, I have another button which should also change the id of the dataprovider when clicked on, but to this:

```
result.datagrid.dataProvider="lineup_2";
```

However, it only responds to the first button pressed on. After that, the id stays the same, which is logic. But I need to know how I can change the id after a button is pressed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say

> result.datagrid.dataProvider="lineup_1";

you do not change dataProvider's id, you change the dataProvider. So at both actions, you change the dataProvider.

More on this, I think you need to make a refresh o your dataprovider after changing. Something like :

```
(result.datagrid.dataProvider as ICollectionView).refresh();
```

Comment: you are right, i see now. but how can i make it so that the dataProvider visibly changes with every button that is being pushed, instead of only the first? :)

Comment: @Kevin: I think that in a DataGrid, if you set the dataProvider right (that means a collection of Objects that can be an ArrayCollection, an XML, XMLList, etc...) every change will be visible without any explicit line of code. Anyway, if it doesn't work, you can try the line posted in my answer. I think that should work.